# DataIntegrityViolationException: same identifier using CRUDRepository

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, crud

I am currently developing an application with Spring (Boot) and JPA. I have the following two entities:

```
@Entity
@AccessType(AccessType.Type.PROPERTY)
@Table(name = "T_ORDER")
public class Order {
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Version
    private Integer version = 0;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Item> items = new ArrayList<>();

    private String text;
    private String status;

    @Deprecated
    public Order() {}

    public static Order newOrder() {
        Order order = new Order();
        order.id = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        return order;
    }

    [... getters and setters ...]

    [... equals and hashCode ...]
}
```

and

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "T_ITEM")
@IdClass(Item.ItemId.class)
public class Item {
    public static class ItemId implements Serializable {
        public String order;
        public String id;
        [... equals and hashcode ...]
    }

    @Id
    @JsonIgnore
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
    private Order order;
    @Id
    private String id;
    @Version
    private int version = 0;
    @Transient
    private Product product;
    private Integer productId;
    private BigDecimal quantity;
    private String quantityUnit;
    private BigDecimal price;

    [... getters and setters ...]
    [... equals and hashcode ...]
}
```

I am using a CRUDRepository

```
@Repository
public interface OrderRepository extends CrudRepository<Order, String> {
    @Transactional
    List<Order> removeByStatus(String status);
}
```

to insert data on application startup

```
@Component
public class OrderLoader implements ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent> {
    private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
    private OrderRepository orderRepository;

    @Autowired
    public void setOrderRepository(OrderRepository orderRepository) {
        this.orderRepository = orderRepository;
    }

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = false)
    public void onApplicationEvent(ContextRefreshedEvent contextRefreshedEvent) {
        try {
            Order order = Order.newOrder();

            for (int itemId = 1; itemId < 3; itemId++) {
                Item item = order.addItem();
                item.setProductId(1);
            }

            order.setText("this is an order");
            order.setStatus("delivered");

            orderRepository.save(order);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.error("This shit...", e);
        }
    }
}
```

Using the H2 console, I can see that the tables are being generated and empty. However, I get a DataIntegrityViolationException when calling orderRepository.save(order).

This seems very strange to me as :

1. The tables are empty,
2. I am using UUIDs as IDs and
3. save should merge two entities with the same key.

The complete stacktrace: http://pastebin.com/gYk2ZvP4

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `orderRepository.saveAndFlush(order);` instead of `orderRepository.save(order);`, with `saveAndFlush` changes will be flushed to DB immediately,while using just `save` changes won't apply to database until `flush` or `commit` are issued.

Comment: As this is a CRUDRepository, it has no flush() or saveAndFlush() methods. I have tried to change it to a JPARepository and use said methods, but the Exception stays the same.

Comment: @3vIL_VIrUs are you sure you are checking the right database ?

Comment: I assume its the right one, as its the only one available to the application and the tables get generated

Comment: @3vIL_VIrUs can you log the id of your Order before the saveAndFlush

Comment: sure: 628adb3f-e357-4c25-bb09-9b6732c770c7
Of course, as this is an UUID it will change every time. I also checked the Item IDs and they are set correctly aswell.